# Docker Image build with modified Autoware source

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Currently, I am using Autoware 1.12.0 with source build. I have modified a few code and its working well with the source build.
Now, I am trying to build docker image for modified Autoware source code, and following is my docker file structure.

```
ARG FROM_ARG
# hadolint ignore=DL3006
FROM ${FROM_ARG}
ARG ROS_DISTRO
ARG VERSION

ENV USERNAME autoware

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

# Build Autoware
COPY ./MY_MODIFIED_CODE_DIR /home/$USERNAME/Autoware 
RUN su -c "source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash; \
           colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'" $USERNAME

RUN echo "source /home/$USERNAME/Autoware/install/local_setup.bash" >> \
    /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

But i am getting error after running **./build.sh** command, with the following error statement.

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c su -c "source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash;            
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'" $USERNAME' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I guess, its because some syntax error in the dockerfile, please can anyone help me how to get rid of this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354483/docker-image-build-with-modified-autoware-source./) by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> RUN su -c "source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash; \
>                colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'" $USERNAME
> ```

Where is that `'` coming from (after `Release`)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-10**:
Note: this is not a ROS problem and is actually *off-topic* for this site.

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2020-06-10**:
@gvdhoorn, thank you so much.